# Как выбрать записи в MySQL используя сумму?

Tags: mysql

Дана таблица с полями id, наименование товара, user_id и сумма единичной покупки. Надо выбрать user_id общая сумма покупок, которых больше 1000, Всю голову уже сломал,

```
SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE SUM(sum)>=1000;
```

- не работает. Зранее спасибо

Comment: 1. @IlyaZhilenkov, Это вопрос на форум [ХэшКод](http://hashcode.ru/).2. SUM почитайте про него: он не так работает это раз. Два, тут нужно использовать либо 2 запроса либо их объединять в один.

Answer (score 2):

пусть есть колонки: id, user_id, price

тогда ваша выборка может выглядеть так:

```
select * from (select user_id, sum(price) as total from table1 group by user_id) as p where total > 1000;
```

или в одном запросе:

```
select user_id, sum(price) as total from table1 group by user_id having total > 1000;
```